# Easy way to get to my fork when I look at the repository I forked from?

Tags: github

GitHub.com provides a useful link to the upstream fork when you view the webpage of your repository. Example:

[image: forked from link]

I want an easy way to do the reverse. When I look at the upstream fork page, I want to know if I've forked it and a quick way to get to my fork. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always fumble around by clicking through the network graph of the upstream fork and I got fed up with it.

I wrote this bit of Javascript that will look for a repository under your username with the same name of the repository you are currently looking at. It does this by issuing a `HEAD` request and checking for a `200` status code.

If it finds a repository under your username with the same name, it assumes it is a fork and inserts a link onto the page for easy access. If it doesn't find one it does nothing.

If you want to use this code, make sure you change `var me = 'fgreg'` to whatever your github username is.

**Disclaimer**: I am not a Javascript programmer, this is probably not efficient code.

**Tested on**: Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) with the Injector 1.0.4 extension enabled

```js
var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "HEAD", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}

if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}

var client = new HttpClient();
var pathname = window.location.pathname
var author = pathname.split('/')[1];
var repoName = pathname.split('/')[2];
console.debug("Extracted {0}/{1} as repo name".format(author, repoName))

var me = 'fgreg'

if(author != me && repoName){

  var forkedUrl = "https://github.com/{0}/{1}".format(me, repoName);
  console.debug("Looking for repo at {0}".format(forkedUrl));
  client.get(forkedUrl, function(anHttpRequest){
    if(anHttpRequest.status == 200){

      var newHtml = '<span class="text">looks like you have a fork: <a href="/{0}/{1}">{0}/{1}</a></span>'.format(me, repoName);
      var forkElement = document.createElement("span")
      forkElement.className = "fork-flag"
      forkElement.innerHTML = newHtml

      var elementPath = "//*[@id=\"js-repo-pjax-container\"]/div[1]/div/h1";
      var element = document.evaluate(elementPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
      console.debug("Found element {0}".format(element))
      element.appendChild(forkElement)

    }else{
      console.debug("No repo found at {0}".format(forkedUrl));
    }

  });
}
```

This is what it ends up looking like:

[image: new fork link]